# Como traduzir um site em PHP?

Tags: php, i18n

Estou fazendo um site simples com apenas algumas páginas **PHP**.
Eu gostaria que esta página fosse traduzível para **português** e **inglês**.
Já utilizo a função `gettext` em **python** e vi que no PHP a sintaxe é muito semelhante.

Código: `gettext('TEXT')` ou `_('TEXT')`

Saída esperada:

**inglês:** TEXT

**português:** TEXTO

Para extrair o arquivo *.po* utilizei o comando `xgettext` e consegui gerar o arquivo de tradução e converter para binário *.mo* tranquilamente. Porém a minha maior dificuldade é carregar os arquivos de tradução no PHP e fazer funcionar corretamente.

Como devo proceder no caso de tradução de arquivos PHP depois disto?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste site, talvez ajude: http://www.devin.com.br/php-gettext/

Comment: Se você tiver o hábito de ler docs em inglês, aqui segue um outro tutorial também. http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html

Comment: Obrigado, @abfurlan, era isso que eu precisava!

Comment: Talvez seja interessante pensar num caminho alternativo. Traduzir o site, imagino, seja ter um site em mais de um idioma, certo? Então eu fortemente recomendo usar um CMS, que já traz isso pronto pra você. Sei que seu site é pequeno, mas mesmo assim, um bom CMS pode reduzir MUITO seu trabalho. Os melhores candidatos são WordPress e Joomla. Obs: eu tenho um site em Joomla, com partes feitas em código PHP.

Comment: @digofreitas será que me podia dar umas luzes/tutos para iniciantes para criar os ficheiros .po e como usar o gettext? Ou alguma ferramenta? Estou completamente as escuras.

Comment: @jorge-b é só ir no link que o romulos recomendou, que explica muito bem

Comment: obrigado @digofreitas mas já cheguei lá sozinho ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que eu faria era:

1) criava uma pasta com o nome "lang"

2) colocava 2 ficheiro eng.php e (pt.php ou eng.php)
exemplo:
    eng.php

```
    <?php 
      $titulo = "My title";
    ?>
```

pt.php

```
    <?php 
      $titulo = "O meu titulo";
    ?>
```

3)faria um botão que adicionava index.php?lang=en, para o caso do ingles

4)Ao longo de todo o site eu atribuia variaveis e nesse ficheiros eu utilizava-as para colocar a respectiva tradução utilizava.

```
    if($_GET['lang'] == "en"){
        include 'eng.php';
     }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title> <?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Desta forma iria evitar o uso de uma base de dados para cada palavra.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 19):

A extensão GetText pode não estar disponível no serviço de hospedagem. Além disso ela não te ajudará muito com tradução de URLs ou registros do BD. Por isso, minha sugestão é você trabalhar com um sistema de tradução mais completo, que pode ser implantado em qualquer site PHP sem dependência da extensão GetText. Essa solução envolve 3 partes:

## Tradução de textos estáticos

Envolve a tradução dos textos fixos do seu site, que estão codificados diretamente no HTML (ou seja, aqueles textos que não são recuperados de um banco de dados). Para esse texto crie arquivos de tradução e uma função que mapeia isso pra você. Grave o idioma do usuário em alguma lugar (sessão ou cookie) de modo que você possa saber a preferência dele e qual mapeamento usar:

**en_us.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'A Empresa'=>'The Company',
    'Contato'=> 'Contact',
    ...
);
```

**translator.php**

```
<?php
function _($text)
{
     session_start();         

     // Exemplo recuperando o idioma da sessao.
     $lang = isset($_SESSION['lang'])?$_SESSION['lang']:'';

     if (!empty($lang))
     {
          // Carrega o array de mapeamento de textos.
          $mapping = require_once $lang.'.php';
          return isset($mapping[$text])?$mapping[$text]:$text;
     }

     return $text;
}
```

**exemplo-de-uso.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'translator.php';
session_start();

// Apenas para teste. O idioma deve ser
// escolhido pelo usuário.
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en_us';

echo _('Contato');
```

## Tradução de textos dinâmicos (do banco de dados)

Crie uma coluna adicional em cada tabela, que especifica o idioma do registro.
Por exemplo, uma tabela de notícias poderia ser:

```
id    titulo              texto                    data          **idioma_id**
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Noticia de teste    Apenas uma noticia      2014-05-16     1
2     Test new            Just a new              2014-05-16     2
```

Na hora de consultar os registros, traga apenas aqueles do idioma desejado:

```
SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE idioma_id = 2;
```

## Tradução de URLs

Envolve a tradução das URLs do site. Para isso funcionar é necessário utilizar um script único de entrada para seu site. Através de um arquivo .htaccess você pode fazer isso, redirecionando qualquer acesso para um arquivo index.php. Após redirecionar, você pode usar um mapeamento das URLs, assim como feito para os textos estáticos:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Nao aplica o redirecionamento caso 
# o que esteja sendo acessado seja um arquivo ou pasta.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redireciona para o arquivo index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**en_us_routes.php**

```
<?php
    return array(
        'the-company'=>'a_empresa.php',
        'contact'=> 'contato.php',
        ...
    );
```

**index.php**

```
// Remove da URL a pasta da aplicacao,
// deixando apenas os parametros.
$aux = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$parameters = str_replace($aux, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Recupera as partes da URL.
// Se você acessar http://meusite.com.br/empresa
// $urlParts será:
//      array('empresa')
//
// Se você acessar http://meusite.com.br/contato
// $urlParts será:
//      array('contato')
$urlParts = explode('/', $parameters);

// Para simplificar, aqui trata uma URL com
// apenas uma parte. Mas você pode generalizar para urls
// com suburls também (Ex: "empresa/onde-estamos").
$url = $urlParts[0];

// Apenas para teste. O idioma pode estar
// associado ao perfil do usuário e ser setado
// na sessão no login.
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en_us';

// Carrega o array de mapeamento de URLs.
$mappingFileName = $_SESSION['lang'].'_routes.php';
$mapping = require_once $mappingFileName ;

if (isset($mapping[$url]))
{
    require_once $mapping[$url];
}
else
{
    require_once 'erro_404.php';
}
```

Os códigos citado são apenas exemplos para passar a ideia (não foram testados).

Comment: Você cobriu bastante terreno com a sua resposta, inclusive um que poucos sites se dão ao trabalho de fazer que é a tradução dos URIs. Mas faltou justamente a parte que o autor citou que é o uso de GetText. Teria como você completar? Se não eu monto um texto bacana aqui.

Comment: O princípio de funcionamento do gettext é o mesmo do citado em "Tradução de textos estáticos". Entretanto, se desejar usar o gettext tem um bom tutorial em http://www.devin.com.br/php-gettext/. Eu particularmente sugiro utilizar um framework que já incorpore classes/métodos de tradução, tal como o Yii Framework (http://www.yiiframework.com/).

Comment: Eu não, obrigado. :) Também sugiro um framework, pelo menos um de domínio específico, só para a tradução pelo menos, principalmente pelo fato de a GetTeext não ser uma extensão muito consoiderada pelas empresas de hospedagem.

Comment: Exato. O problema do GetText é esse! :)

Comment: Obrigado pelo capricho na resposta, @arivan-bastos mas realmente esta abordagem não era o que eu queria.
Consegui realizar tudo que precisava com este tutorial:
http://www.devin.com.br/php-gettext/

Comment: Boa resposta. +1. Mas, fica a dica: "*news*" é [incontável](https://jakubmarian.com/news-is-vs-news-are-jeans-is-vs-jeans-are-etc-in-english/) em inglês. :)