# Como tornar um site multilíngue?

Tags: php

Tenho um site feito em PHP, agora surgiu-me a obrigatoriedade de tornar o site multilingue.
Preciso de traduzir títulos, menus e mensagens de erro. Textos adicionados a posteriori pelo utilizador não precisam de ser traduzidos.

Já vi vários tipos de abordagens como:

### Definição de constantes:

Consiste em definir constantes em diferentes ficheiros PHP, por exemplo pt_PT.php e depois fazer a inclusão `include 'pt_PT.php';` das traduções antes do carregamento da página.

Exemplo:   `define( 'USER' , 'UTILIZADOR' );`

### Definição de *arrays*:

Consiste em definir *arrays* também com inclusão `include 'pt_PT.php';`.

Exemplo: `$lang['USER'] = 'UTILIZADOR';`

Exemplo [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16154/7210).

### Gettext:

Depois de ver [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937/como-traduzir-um-site-em-php) descobri que pode ser pela função `gettext`.

*Para quem precisar tem* [aqui](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/) *um mini tutorial para utilizar o* [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html) *e o* [poEdit](http://poedit.net/)

### Base de Dados:

Há também a possibilidade de guardar as traduções numa tabela de traduções.

```
+-------+------------+--------+-----
|sigla  | pt_PT      | en     | ...
+-------+------------+--------+-----
| usr   | utilizador | user   | ...
+-------+------------+--------+-----
```

### Páginas diferentes para cada língua:

Já vi também, ter páginas replicadas para diferentes línguas:

[www.myhost.pt/en/index.php](http://www.myhost.pt/en/index.php)
[www.myhost.pt/pt_PT/index.php](http://www.myhost.pt/en/index.php)

---

No meu caso que não preciso de ter tradução de conteúdo, qual é a melhor opção?

Vantagens/Desvantagens?

Existe alguma opção melhor? Qual?

*PS: a solução mais consensual que tenho visto é através do gettext.*

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937/como-traduzir-um-site-em-php)

Comment: Não é duplicata, eu refiro essa questão. A minha pergunta é bem diferente. Ao menos deram-se ao trabalho de ler as perguntas?

Comment: No link da **possível** dusplicata, tem uma excelente resposta do @ArivanBasos

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Editei a pergunta e adicionei o exemplo da resposta que identificaste.

Comment: Agora a sinalização de duplicata não faz mais sentido. Eu a removi, porém agora ela poderia ser classificada como "baseada em opiniões" pois para saber o melhor modo, seriam necessários pontos de vista de quem já usou todos as alternativas e obteve um certo benchmark. Mas aparentemente eu não posso votar de novo.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21837/7210) tens algumas desvantagens dos métodos em array e constantes. Não tem nada a ver com opiniões. É uma pergunta de vantagens e desvantagens sendo que não traduzo conteúdo.

Answer (score 9):

## A solução que eu uso:

Criei um arquivo com uma array de tradução para cada língua, e fiz a definição da linguagem na página.

languages.php

```
<?php
/*
#
# Translations system
# (C)2014 - MyEnterprise
#
*/

// Criar a array de todas as linguas
$translationsArray = array();

// Criar a array para cada lingua
$translationsArray["pt_BR"] = array();
$translationsArray["en_US"] = array();

# PT-BR            $lang     $string
$translationsArray["pt_BR"]["HelloWorld"] = "Olá mundo!";
$translationsArray["pt_BR"]["Title"]      = "Título";
$translationsArray["pt_BR"]["Welcome"]    = "Seja bem-vindo a %s";

# EN-US            $lang     $string
$translationsArray["en_US"]["HelloWorld"] = "hello World!";
$translationsArray["en_US"]["Title"]      = "Title";
$translationsArray["en_US"]["Welcome"]    = "Welcome to %s";
```

index.php

```
    <?php
// função para pegar string do arquivo languages.php
function getLanguageString($string, $lang="pt_BR", $parameters=null) {
    /*
    / levando em conta como exemplo: 
    / $translationsArray["pt_BR"]["Welcome"]    = "Seja bem-vindo a %s";
    /
    / $string = "ID" da string, seria o "Welcome"
    / $lang = A lingua para pegar a string, no caso pt_BR ou en_US
    / $parameters = uma array de valores para substituir os %s se tiver algum(s)
    */

// incluir o arquivo languages.php ou abortar o script
if (!require("languages.php")) {
    die("ERRO ao carregar arquivo de linguas");
}

    $actualTranslatedString = $translationsArray[$lang][$string];

    if (!empty($parameters)) {
        return vsprintf($actualTranslatedString, $parameters);
    }
    else {
        return $actualTranslatedString;
    }
}

// Exemplo:
$siteLang = "pt_BR";
$siteName = "GitHub";
$parameters = array(
    0 => $siteName
);

$bemVindo = getLanguageString("Welcome", $siteLang, $parameters); 
echo $bemVindo;
```

Aqui funcionou. \o

Comment: pq o -1? apenas dei uma sugestão..

Comment: Estranho -1, pois sim... A código está bem comentado e normalmente uma resposta de baixa qualidade é simplesmente um copy/paste de código sem explicação nenhuma. Talvez [este comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21788/como-tornar-um-site-multil%c3%adngue#comment39461_21837) explique alguma coisa... note que o comentário tem dois votos, o -1 pode ter vindo de qualquer um...

Comment: O -1 deve ter sido por mostrar a implementação por *array*, mas não é isso que eu pergunto, eu pergunto qual a melhor alternativa. Vantagens e desvantagens de umas e outras. De qualquer forma é muito boa a sua sugestão. +1

Answer (score 7):

As formas citadas são válidas e funcionais, porém vejo um problema em utilizar ***constantes*** e ***arrays*** para este fim, você pode esquecer de definir algum desses para um determinado idioma e terá problemas.

Uma sugestão seria utilizar uma interface e as classes com métodos que retornam o texto, exemplo:

```
interface Language {
    public function getLabelNome();
}

class ptBR implements Language {

    public function getLabelNome(){
       return "Nome";
   }

}

class enUS implements Language {
    public function getLabelNome() {
        return "Name";
    }
}

class esES implements Language{
    public function getLabelNome() {
        return "Nombre";
    }

}
```

Quando o usuário escolher a linguagem, você instancia a classe dessa linguagem, desta forma com o auxílio da interface, você garante que terá todas as traduções disponíveis.

Outra vantagem utilizando métodos é que você pode tratar a forma de retorno do texto, exemplo

```
public function getLabelNome($uper = false){
    return $uper ? "NOME" : "Nome";
}

$lang = new ptBR();
echo $lang->getLabelNome(true); // retorna em maiúsculo
```

#### Editado

*Conforme mencionado por @Kazzkiq nos comentários abaixo, outra vantagem seria de não permitir o usuário alterar o valor das palavras fora do arquivo onde elas são criadas.*

Comment: Na minha opinião, esta é a solução mais organizada e padronizada disponível. Além de ter a vantagem de não permitir o usuário alterar o valor das palavras fora do  arquivo onde elas são criadas. (No caso do `array`, eu poderia facilmente editar o valor de uma palavra e estragar qualquer código que usasse ela dali pra baixo)

Comment: Bem colocado @Kazzkiq, outra vantagem :)

Comment: Boa solucão, o tradutor fica limitado a uma classe, sem alterar a outra.

Comment: Mais uma alternativa, e o porque de não usar *arrays* nem *constantes*. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Bem a solução que adotei, depois de muito estudo e conversação aqui no escritório, foi [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) com [poEdit](http://poedit.net/).

Aqui fica um tutorial por onde me guiei: [PHP and Javascript Internationalization using Gettext and Poedit](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/php-javascript-internationalization-gettext-poedit)

É simples e eficaz,

1 - Instalar o poEdit e o gettext como no tutorial acima* ;

2 - Substituir no código PHP as nossas mensagens/nomesDeMenus por `_("mensagem")`;

3 - Abrir o editor poEditor* e atualizar, carrega as mensagens a traduzir como id's;

4 - É só traduzir, guardar o ficheiro `.po` no sito correto e esta andar.

<sub>*sei que está em inglês, mas não vou traduzir, pois não é essa a ideia da resposta.</sub>

Para traduzir os meus tipos de utilizador que estão na BD criei uma classe que imprime o resultado vindo da BD para um ficheiro `translate.php` e a partir dai posso fazer a tradução com o [poEdit](http://poedit.net/), fica o exemplo:

```
public function createArrayTipo()
{
    $filePHP   = fopen("translate.php", "a");
    $inicial = true;

    if (!is_resource($filePHP))
        return false;

    $sql_activity     = "SELECT id, name FROM user_type";
    $result_activity  = mysqli_query( $this->mysqli , $sql_activity  );

    fwrite($filePHP, "\n  \$tipos_user = array(");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_activity))
        {
        if(!$inicial)
        fwrite($filePHP, ",");

        fwrite($filePHP, "'".$row['id']."' => _('".$row['name']."')" );

        $inicial = false;
    }
    fwrite($filePHP, "); \n");
    fclose($filePHP);
}
```

A minha pergunta continua sem resposta, mas aqui fica mais uma opção.