# Como tornar um site multilíngue e identificar o país de origem?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, aplicação-web, ip

Estou desenvolvendo um site em JavaEE e gostaria de que fosse multilíngue (pelo menos inglês, português e espanhol). Porém gostaria de saber como os sites grandes, tais quais como o Facebook, por exemplo, fazem para identificar o país de origem e oferecer o site na língua daquele país.

Sei que existem várias formas de fazer isso, através de tabelas e consultas no banco de dados, com arrays, já vi até mesmo através de uma [cópia de todos os arquivos](https://www.dropbox.com/pt_BR/) com suas devidas traduções localizados em um outro diretório do servidor.

O Dropbox, por exemplo, usa [Javascript](https://www.dropbox.com/static/javascript/langpack/pt_BR.js).

Gostaria de saber qual dessas formas é a que menos sobrecarrega o servidor (e se existem outras formas?) e como posso fazer para identificar qual é a língua do meu visitante. Também gostaria de saber qual é a melhor forma para futuras manutenções e ajustes, desconsiderando a performance.

Comment: Obs: Não é uma duplicata de: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21788/como-tornar-um-site-multil%C3%ADngue Note que desejo saber qual das opções é a mais viável e gostaria de saber como identificar a língua do meu visitante.

Comment: Esta pergunta terminará aparecendo aqui também: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qlgqy.png :) Note que a tag é adicionada automaticamente no `<title>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O idioma preferido do usuário é provavelmente o que está configurado no navegador, que normalmente é o idioma (e *locale*) do sistema operacional.

Você pode checar esse idioma no cabeçalho (header) `Accept-Language` que acompanha a requisição. Um exemplo do valor contido nesse cabeçalho é `en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6`.

A primeira parte, antes da primeira `,` é a *language tag*. Nesse caso `en-US`. Esse formato é um padrão do IETF que você pode ler mais buscando por "IETF language tags."

Para testar seu site com diferentes idiomas você pode mudar o *locale* do seu navegador e/ou do sistema operacional e refrescar a página. A forma de mudar o idioma/locale varia de navegador para navegador e SO para SO. No Google Chrome, por exemplo, você pode ir para *chrome://settings/languages* e reordenar/adicionar idiomas.

Comment: Sabe dizer se existe uma definição de ip´s por países? Gostaria de traduzir meu site para o inglês sempre que o acesso fosse feito de um ip que não seja do Brasil.