# Site multi idioma / Multi Linguagem (Detecção de país automático sem permissão)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, htaccess

Tenho um pequeno projeto e gostaria de criar um sistema de multi linguagem para o site.
Encontrei várias formas aqui no site, porém não vi nenhuma com esse exemplo, que inclusive o stackoverflow também usa.

Como fazer?

Desta forma identifico o país e traduzindo automaticamente.

`pt.domain.com`

ou Desta o site traduzir automaticamente pela localização do usuário sem mudar a extenção no site.

```
domain.com
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer o processo de multi-lang por `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta já foi feita aqui no Stackoverflow e várias delas já te respondem como fazer o que você quer, ou melhor, nenhuma delas realmente dizem como você deve fazer, apenas te dão as possibilidades, porque não existe a melhor maneira, isso depende muito de como você conduz/desenvolve seu website/webapp.

A melhor forma de detectar a linguagem do usuário seria por `Accept-Language`, que pega o idioma preferido do browser da pessoa, eu por exemplo, prefiro inglês, então maioria dos sites que eu entro, ele me redireciona pra versão americana (en-US).

Com apenas este link abaixo você já consegue achar suas respostas. 
[Como tornar um site multilíngue e identificar o país de origem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30982/como-tornar-um-site-multil%C3%ADngue-e-identificar-o-pa%C3%ADs-de-origem)

Alguns usam o que você deseja saber, o 'pt.domain.com', nada mais é que um subdomínio, mas acredite, não há nada de tradução "automática", e sim apenas a detecção da linguagem do usuário e então depende deles mesmo decidirem como vão traduzir, exemplos:

meusite.com/en-US/index.php,
meusite.com/pt-BR/index.php,

Ou traduções dos menus e etc salvas no banco de dados e então quando detectado a linguagem, a tradução é buscada no banco de dados e retornado.

Ou como você viu, um subdomínio contendo o mesmo sistema, só que traduzido.

Espero que eu tenha ajudado.

Comment: A princípio vou usar esse metodo, mesmo achando um pouco simples e prevendo um suposto erro mais tarde. Mas ajudou MUITO! Obrigado