# Como fazer um site multilíngue?

Tags: php, html

Eu já tive a pesquisar sobre o assunto neste site e noutros, e esta pergunta pareceu-me a mais completa: [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21788/como-tornar-um-site-multil%C3%ADngue) , a minha pergunta é: é necessário fazer com os arrays de linguagem, ... ou posso simplesmente duplicar a pagina, por exemplo: index.html e fazer uma index_es.html e fazer assim para todas? E se sim, este método tem alguma desvantagem, ou é errado utiliza-lo?

Comment: A solução do array com as linguagens é normalmente a chamada de i18n. Nem sempre isso é possível. Ela é adequada quando os trechos a serem traduzidos são curtos e tem muita coisa repetida. Por exemplo, a label "usuário", ela pode se encontrar em diversos cantos. Caso a página tenha um grande conteúdo textual, traduzir com aquela estratégia talvez não seja a melhor coisa do mundo (principalmente quando vai para uma língua que foge do SVO, bem distinta do português). Para esse caso, multiplexar o "artigo" em diversos idiomas pode ser o mais indicado.

Comment: e a outra solução, de duplicar as paginas é viável?

Comment: Terminei o comentário anterior agora. São estratégias distintas que tem usos e vantagens distintas. Cada uma deve ser aplicada onde é melhor de se aplicar.

Comment: Por exemplo, aqui no SOpt: a parte da ajuda do site é um texto mais pesado. Possivelmente você pode desejar mantê-lo de maneira separada. Mas essas pequenas frases e mensagens da parte principal, como "fazer uma pergunta" e outras mensagens mais, não faz sentido separar

Answer (score 3):

Se você observar com cuidado, Blogspot, Facebook, Google, Amazon principalmente, todas estas empresas multinacionais possuem diferentes diretórios para diferentes idiomas.

O que pode fazer é no seu website, fazer num canto superior, direito ou esquerdo, uma hiperligação com a bandeira do país e assim, encaminhar para um diferente diretório.

Penso que seja menos penoso e com menos probabilidade de erro.

Outra coisa que pode fazer é possuir um ficheiro .txt para um idioma. Nesse ficheiro, introduzir uma lista das palavras mais comuns de um idioma e depois fazer um script onde é captadoa as palavras no histórico do browser da pessoa. Se as palavras do histórico coincidirem com as palavras do ficheiro .txt do idioma desejado, atualizar website para o idioma desejado.

Por exemplo, um Francês tem palavras francesas no seu histórico. A script vai captar essas palavraa e procurá-las nos ficheiros .txt. Quando as palavras do histórico coincidirem com as palavras do ficheiro .txt do idioma francês, o website atualiza.