# Site em dois idiomas

Tags: php, mysql

Terei que desenvolver um site em dois idiomas, Português e Inglês. Nada complexo, porém estou em dúvidas em como organizar a estrutura, portanto gostaria da opinião de alguém que já tenha estado na minha atual situação.

O site deverá abrir em português e no topo de cada página terá uma bandeira americana que levará para a página em inglês, caso o usuário tenha interesse.Por exemplo, usuário está na index e vai para a página contato, o site segue o fluxo normal em português. Caso o usuário acesse a index e troque de idioma, será carregada a mesma index em inglês e então se clicar em 'contato', a página contato será carregada em inglês. Quando o idioma é português, no topo haverá uma bandeira americana (botão) para troca de idioma, e vice-versa.

Como posso estruturar isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Sim é possível fazer com php puro. Vai de criar um ou mais arquivos com um array contendo o indentificadores e valores repectivos ou guarda isso no banco de dados. Ali no lado direito tem a area de perguntas `relacionadas` dê uma olha também sempre tem coisas interessantes sobre o tema.

Comment: @rray quem dera ter um recurso semelhante ao do android para internacionalização hein,.

Comment: A solução mais robusta é usar o [gettext](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.gettext.php), este é um bom tutorial: http://www.devin.com.br/php-gettext/.

Comment: Aqui tem um bom tutorial para isso: http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html
Hj não faço mais assim. Prefiro usar o WordPress com o WPML plugin.

Comment: Se o link indicado acima não contiver resposta adequada para a pergunta, você pode [edit] a mesma acrescentando as especificidades do seu problema que sejam diferentes daquela. Alternativamente, aqui tem outro _approach_ para o mesmo problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937 - Qualquer coisa, deixe um comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jeito mais simples que achei foi usando o `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` que vai pegar as linguagens do `browser`, sendo a primeira a principal do usuário. Após isso resgatamos as traduções salvas em vários arquivos de linguagem (um ou mais para cada linguagem).

No exemplo, caso o navegador esteja em outro idioma sem ser inglês ou português ele irá apresentar o site em inglês,

E usamos no site, veja um exemplo:

---

*Arquivos de idioma:*

São definidos por um conjunto de chaves e valores:

```
chave = 'valor'
chave = 'valor'
```

**pt-br.lang:**

```
welcome = 'Bem-Vindo'
bye = 'Tchau.'
lng = 'Idioma:'
```

**en-us.lang:**

```
welcome = 'Welcome'
bye = 'Bye, Bye'
lng = 'Language:'
```

Note que as chaves sempre são iguais, apenas o valor que deve ter o conteúdo no idioma definido.

---

*Página do site:*

Aqui é onde definidos o layout do site, antes de tudo pegamos o idioma, exemplo:

**index.html:**

```
<?php

$idioma = explode(",", $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);

if(file_exists(strtolower($idioma[0]).'.lang'))
{
    $lng = parse_ini_file(strtolower($idioma[0]).'.lang');
}
else
{
    $lng = parse_ini_file('en-us.lang');
}

echo <<<SAUDACAO
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <p>{$lng['lng']} {$idioma[0]}</p>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p>{$lng['welcome']}</p>
        </td>

        <td>
        <p>{$lng['bye']}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
SAUDACAO;

?>
```

Caso queira que o usuário selecione o idioma é só fazer um link para cada idioma, com a ação de alterar a variável `$idioma` para `pt-br` ou `en-us`.

Para testar o exemplo acima, roda uma vez com o navegador em português, após isso mudo o idioma do mesmo e acesse novamente o `index.php`.