# Adicionando linguagem manualmente

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá,

Estou trabalhando em cima de um site, onde o cliente me passou em pdf dos textos do site, em outra lingua, para assim, eu adicionar uma opção no site para mudar a linguagem.

*o site nao é em wordpress.

porem eu nao sei nem por onde começa a fazer isso, Alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

THANKS

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada em: [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15937/91), [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21788/91) e [Site em dois idiomas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110553/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de definir diferentes idiomas ao site. Talvez a mais recomendada seja utilizar [Gettext](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) uma biblioteca `GNU`.

Uma forma alternativa (e que uso) é utilizar objetos `javascript` e linkalos a sua página e utilizar uma função em `javascript` para "traduzir" o source.

Um exemplo simples seria definir um arquivo (objecto) como padrão e carregar outros pela iteração do usuário com `$_POST` por exemplo.

Contudo note que essa "tradução" só ocorreria após o `load` da página diferente de `gettext` que já traduz na saída do `PHP`.

Essa opção também delega ao usuário o custo deste processamento por isso fica a observação que talvez não seja recomendada para ser utilizada com um source de grande volume.

Seria possível também criar um `cookie` para lembrar a opção de idioma do usuário más esta questão não abordarei no exemplo.

### index.php

```
<?php
// array de idiomas permitidos
$allowed_languages = ['en-US','pt-BR'];
// verificar se houve um post e se é um valor permitido
if( isset($_POST['lang']) AND in_array($_POST['lang'], $allowed_languages) ){
    // definir o novo caminho
    $lang_path = 'path/tojslanguage/i18n_'.$_POST['lang'].'.js';
    // salvar em sessão (para recuperar e outros pontos ou no reload)
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];
}else{
    // verificar se ha sessão
    if( isset($_SESSION['lang']) ){
       // recuperar
       $lang_path = 'path/tojslanguage/i18n_'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.js';
    }else{
       // definir um valor padrão
       $lang_path = 'path/tojslanguage/i18n_en-US.js';
       // salvar sessão (valor default)
       $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en-US';
    }
}

// Neste ponto seria interessante utilizar a sessão na tag `<html lang="">`
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>

   <!--
     os atributos recomendados para servirem de referencia ao javascript
     seriam: "class" e "data-".

     como exemplo deixo uma h1 a ser traduzida e botões para disparar a ação
   -->

   <h1 data-html="words.title" class="i18n"></h1>

   <button id="en-US" data-html="words.USlang" class="i18n choose-lang"></button><br>

   <button id="pt-BR" data-html="words.BRlang" class="i18n choose-lang"></button>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $lang_path; ?>"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  //
  var wd = window,
      dc = document,
      XHR = (new XMLHttpRequest()),
      FD  = (new FormData());

  // função para disparar um post
  var requestPost = function(url, params, callback){
      // catch response
      XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200){
             if(callback){
                callback(XHR.responseText);
             }
          }
      }
      // open
      XHR.open('POST', url, true);
      /**
       * set header [obsolete in use FormData API]
       * XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
       */
      // check
      if(!params || typeof params !== 'object' || Object.keys(params).length < 1){
         return false;
      }else{
         var keys = Object.keys(params),
             i    = keys.length;
         // loop (inverse)
         while(i--){
           FD.append(keys[i], params[keys[i]]);
         }
         // send
         XHR.send(FD);
      }
  };

  var choose_lang = dc.getElementsByClassName('choose-lang');
  //loop
  for(var i = 0; i < choose_lang.length; i++){
      //
      choose_lang[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         // recupar o id (idioma)
         var language = this.getAttribute('id');
         requestPost('./', {lang: language});
         location.reload(true);
      });
  }

  var ilib = function(){
      // buscar referencia
      var set = dc.getElementsByClassName('i18n');
      // fazer o loop para buscar todas as referencias
      for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
          // capturar a referencia do objecto
          var html  = set[i].getAttribute('data-html');
          // checar se há (existe) valor definido
          if(!!html && typeof html !== undefined){
             // separar referencias
             var transc = set[i].getAttribute('data-html').split('.');
             /**
               checar o número de palavras...
               note neste exemplo apenas duas más é possíveis definir varias
              */
              if(transc[2]){
                 var word = i18n[transc[0]][transc[1]][transc[2]];
              }else{
                 var word = i18n[transc[0]][transc[1]];
              }
              // aplicar tradução
              set[i].innerHTML = word;
          }
      }
  };
  // dispara tradução após carregar a página
  wd.onload = ilib();
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

### i18n_en-US.js

```
var i18n = {
    words: {
       title: 'Welcome to site.com',
       USlang: 'Englis (USA)',
       BRlang: 'Portuguese (Brazil)'
    }
};
```

### i18n_pt-BR.js

```
var i18n = {
    words: {
       title: 'Bem vindo ao site.com',
       USlang: 'Ingles (USA)',
       BRlang: 'Portugues (Brasil)'
    }
};
```

---

Este exemplo esta em `javascript` puro más é possível utilizar|adaptar via `jQuery` para facilitar por exemplo: "preppends" ou "appends" é possível utilizar para definir placeholders, titles, alt, etc...

Para inserir valores vindos de referencia pelo `PHP` como do banco de dados basta colocar os valores seguindo esta lógica dentro do atibuto `data-html=""`.

### exemplo:

```
<?php
   // exemplo ficticio de um valor salvo no banco de dados
   $value = 'words.palavara_qualquer';
?>

<a data-html="<?php echo $value; ?>" class="i18n" href="#"></a>
```

Nestes exemplos é possível criar um indice e sub-indices dentro do objeto:

```
// o objeto em si (i18n)
var i18n = {

    // um indice (words)
    words: {
       // um sub-indice (ou item)
       title: 'Uma palavra qualquer um uma frase'
    },
    // outro indice
    teplates: {
       // um sub-item de templates
       dark: 'Escuro'
    }

};
```

Para um código fonte estável (finalizado) e que não seja extenso acredito ser uma boa alternativa pois salvando em cache os arquivos `javascript` não ira impactar na experiencia do usuário para com o site.

Agora para projetos de constante manutenção toda vez que houver mudanças nos arquivos de idioma o usuário terá de fazer o download novamente para cache.

Nota: exemplo funcional.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui resolver usando o seu post!! Thanks <3