# Como traduzir meu site automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript

estou desenvolvendo um site(www.asbesc.org.br) para meu tio e o mesmo precisa de que o site fique em até 3 idiomas, porém eu não faço a menor ideia de como fazer isso, um amigo me disse que por PHP daria certo da seguinte maneira:

Eu criaria 3 pastas, cada uma contendo seus textos em cada idioma especifico e dai chamaria uma função pra saber qual é o idioma do navegador da pessoa e depois viria uma condição se o idioma for 'tal' redirecionava o usuário para a pasta desse idioma, por exemplo:

www.asbesc.org.br/en ou www.asbesc.org.br/pt

Não sei se esse é o jeito certo de se fazer e também não sei se daria certo!

Comment: Talvez possa ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15937/6454