# Traduzir site PHP com strings via require

Tags: php, html

Tenho um site em *PHP* e estou traduzindo ele da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/translate.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $site_title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="welcome"><?php echo $div_welcome; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

O `require` contém o arquivo `translate.php`:

```
<?php
$language = $_GET['lang'];
if ($language == "pt") {
insira o código aqui
    $site_title = "Blog do Antonny";
    $div_welcome = "Seja bem-vindo(a) no meu Blog"; 
} 
if ($language == "es") {
    $site_title = "Blog de Antonny";
    $div_welcome = "Bienvenido a mi Blog";
} 
if ($language == "en") {
    $site_title = "Antonny's Blog";
    $div_welcome = "Welcome to my Blog";
}
?>
```

E no `translate.php` são configuradas todas as variáveis com as traduções para cada idioma. Essa foi a forma mais dinâmica que consegui pensar, existe algo que possa tornar essa tradução mais dinâmica? Essa é uma forma incorreta de fazer?

Comment: Já viu essa pergunta aqui no site? [Como traduzir um site em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937/como-traduzir-um-site-em-php?rq=1)

Comment: Se forem poucas palavras não vejo inconvenientes porém se esse arquivo translate.php ficar imenso eu criaria 3 arquivos,  langPT.php, langES.php e langEN.php. Daí if ($language == "pt") { require_once("includes/langPT.php"); } elseif ($language == "es"){require_once("includes/langES.php"); .....

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937/como-traduzir-um-site-em-php)