# Estrutura de pastas e ficheiros em site multi-língua

Tags: php, html

Bom dia,
estou a estruturar um site multi-língua com os seguintes sub-directorios:

- dominio.com/PT
- dominio.com/EN

Posso ter um index em cada uma destas pastas?

Eu faço esta pergunta porque fico na dúvida se devo ter um index em dominio.com que linka para as páginas das línguas nas diretorias que criei ou se apenas existem index nas pastas de sub-diretoria.

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15937/como-traduzir-um-site-em-php)

Comment: A minha questão está relacionada com a estrutura de pastas e ficheiros que é necessário criar no servidor de hospedagem e não propriamente com os comandos php necessários para se efetuar uma tradução de texto. Obrigado.

Comment: Você tá utilizando algum framework ou CMS?

Comment: Neste momento o site ainda não está publicado e estou a criá-lo no meu pc com visual studio code mas fico na dúvida sobre a estrutura de pastas e ficheiros. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem varias formas de se fazer uma estrutura dessas, você pode criar um arquivo onde ficara salva todos os textos do seu site.

crie um arquivo para os idiomas que você quiser exemplo:

textos-pt.php

```
<?php

$titulo = "Meu carro"
$descricao = "Um carro qualquer"

?>
```

textos-en.php

```
<?php

$titulo = "My car"
$descricao = "Any car"

?>
```

No seu site ao invés de escrever diretamente os textos você chama as variáveis, caso seja /pt você chama o arquivo  textos-pt.php e assim por diante

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. A minha questão está mais relacionada com a estrutura de ficheiros que têm de ser criados no servidor.